# I try to display json data on alert but cannot display anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I try to display json data on alert but cannot display anything. I have a json file named json_data.txt 
and here are my codes;

```
        $.getJSON('json_data.txt', function(read_data){
            $.each(read_data.movies,function(i,movie){

               alert("Movie Name:"+movie.name+" Actresses:"+movie.actress+" Actors"+movie.actor)

            });
        });
```

Comment: Do you get errors in the console? Add a `console.log(read_data)` just before the `$.each()` and tell us what it outputs. Also please edit your question to show (at least some of) json_data.txt.

Comment: Its not a json file if its .txt - it should be .json. Plus there is so little information here that its hard to know where the issue is

Comment: @Craicerjack - the file name can be anything; it certainly doesn't have to be .json. (It doesn't even have to be a "file" per se: it could be a URL to a servlet or whatever, as long as the response actually is in JSON format.)

Comment: @nnnnnn you are of course correct, so long as its json.

Comment: @nnnnnn there was any error in console.

Comment: @Craicerjack actually it doesn't have to be .json. In normally, it works on .txt format because I run the files on my webserver and now it's working perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, based on you accessing a simple txt file, you are running this locally on your computer without a webserver.
Some webbrowsers (for example chrome) do not allow javascript to read local files. Hence, in this case jquery would not get access to json_data.txt and be unable to obtain data.

Comment: I run the files on my server and it worked. Thank you.